# Returning subseted data in SQL with original data

Tags: sql

I have a database of students and teachers in a school and the marks scored in a subject in a single table.

```
Teacher | Student | Score

Judy    | Jack    | 45
Judy    | Jane    | 48
John    | Jerry   | 37
```

I need an SQL query that returns the proportion of students who score > 40, grouped by teacher.

I cant think of any efficient way of doing this, without using a temp table.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So what's the expected result (with that table data?)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Teacher, SUM(CASE WHEN Score > 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*)
FROM marks
GROUP BY Teacher
```

Comment: Small mistake: Either `COUNT(CASE WHEN Score > 40 THEN 1 ELSE null END)` or `SUM(CASE WHEN Score > 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Shame on me for making that mistake.  I tried downvoting myself but it wouldn't let me :-)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with `CASE` within a `sum`:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST (Teacher varchar(32), Student varchar(32), score int)

INSERT INTO #TEST (Teacher,Student,score)
VALUES
('Adam','Berta',32),
('Adam','Cecil',41),
('Adam','David',52),
('Erik','Fredrick',43),
('Erik','Georgia',66)


SELECT Teacher,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Score > 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Success,
       COUNT(Student) AS Total,
       100*SUM(CASE WHEN Score > 40 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(Student) AS Fraction
FROM #TEST
GROUP BY Teacher

DROP TABLE #TEST
```

The result I got from this was:

```
Teacher Success Total   Fraction

Adam    2   3   66
Erik    2   2   100
```